# why set default parameter then run if statement in python?

Tags: python

I came across code that looks like:

```
def plot_svc(model, ax=None, plot_support=True):
    """function to plot 2-D SVC"""
    if ax is None:
        ax=plt.gca()
```

if we are going to set default parameter `ax=None` why use if statement, don't we know that `ax` is `None`?
So can't we just write:

```
def plot_svc(model, ax=None, plot_support=True):
    """function to plot 2-D SVC"""
    ax=plt.gca()
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ax=None` is a default parameter in the sense that it will take that value if `ax` is not explicitly specified in the function call. You don't necessary know what value it might take, but you can handle the case where the user doesn't provide any value at all

Comment: Oh okay so if user inputs ax=None all the time there is no need for that ax=None parameter?

Comment: Why do you think it's called the "default"?  Look at entry #6 in the dictionary.  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/default

Comment: If they specified it as `None` on _every_ function call, then yes, it would be equivalent. You're just giving a default value if it's _not_ specified, and nothing about doing that suggests that a user wouldn't actually want to specify it.

Comment: Note that in this case you can shorten that to `ax = ax or plt.gca()`.

Comment: @cglacet that is not equivalent, and indeed, a main motivating reason behind the addition of conditional expressions was to avoid people using those sorts of constructs.

Comment: I never said it was equivalent, but in this case `ax` will never evaluate to false if it's a proper axis object, so in some way it's just fine in this case (or I'm missing something?). On the other hand I agree that having an operator for it would be better.

Comment: @cglacet right, you are thinking of the conditional exression: `x if cond else y`, see the [motivations behind the PEP that added them](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/#adding-a-conditional-expression)

Comment: Ah I thought you meant [PEP 505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ax might not be None when the function is called.

```
def f(x=None):
    if x is None:
        return True
    return False

>>> f(None)
True
>>> f()
True
>>> f(3)
False
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't know default parameters can be overwritten

Answer (score 1):

No.  `ax=None` says what value to give **ax** if it isn't explicitly provided.  If it is explicitly provided, it might not be **None**.

If I call the method in question this way:

foo.plot_svc(model, someNonNullValue)

Then **ax** will be the value in **someNoneNullValue**, not **None**.

Comment: wait so if I set default parameter and user inputs ax=something_else that will override my default ax=None?

Comment: @h_musk Yes, it will.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That's the whole purpose of this construct in Python.  That's why it is called a **default** parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Default parameters make a parameter *optional*, not discluded from the function. So when you call this:

```
plot_svc(my_model, my_ax, plot_support=True)
```

You're using all the arguments, so `ax` is defined in the scope. But if I do this:

```
plot_svc(my_model, plot_support=True)
```

... the function assumes that `ax` is None because that's what you set the default parameter as. So then if the user doesn't pass in `ax`, then `ax` can be set inside the function.

IMO, a most likely better solution would be to do this:

```
def plot_svc(model, ax=plt.gca(), plot_support=True):
    ...
```

Because the way the code currently has it, basically it's redundantly checking if we want to fallback to the default instead of just including `plt.gca` as the default.

*As for what `plt.gca` does, I don't know, please include the library you're using.*

Comment: `plt` is almost surely from `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: @wim Yeah, probably. I'm not a `matplotlib` guy.